# Resolving SBT, scala dependencies manually

Tags: build, sbt, local, chisel

I've just started using Rocket chip as a part of a new project in
my team. I've successfully downloaded Rocket chip generator, compiled
it as is and with some customized configurations, and it works fine.

However, the above listed works were done in my personal desktop where
it has no problem in accessing web proxies. However, at my work, there
are so many restrictions that makes things difficult, and one of them is 
I am unable to build any of rocket projects since sbt fails to resolve build
dependencies. It always ends with the messages that it fails to access
some proxies and cannot download tool dependencies.

I tried to manually download and install sbt, scala or chisel and then retry
the build but it still fails.

Is there a way to manually download all the prerequisites for the rocket build, and then build them without any online accesses? (In other words, offline.)

Unresolved dependencies are as follows.

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-ghpages;0.5.3: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-buildinfo;0.5.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.6: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.11: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.6: not found
```

Comment: This is a Chisel/SBT question, not a RISC-V question.

Comment: Thanks. I changed tags.
BTW, my problem seems to be almost the same as the following link, and it doesn't seem to have any respose either.
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/storm-user/5YTtIwoSinU